# How can I determine the model year of my GT Talera bike?

Tags: serial-number

How can I determine the model year of my GT Talera bike? The serial number starts out as CM17F5

Comment: Unless the manufacturer has a web site with the info you're SOL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you own it, try registering the bike on the GT website at http://www.gtbicycles.com/can_en/bike-registration

You'll need to provide contact info of course.

Answer (score 0):

To find the year of a specific bike, it is sometimes useful this site:
https://www.bikepedia.com/Year.aspx?search=gt%20talera

However, a certain "bike year" can be different for different countries, spec's can be different as well.